# Slice 3D ndarray with 2D ndarray in numpy?

Tags: numpy, scipy

My apologies if this has been answered many times, but I just can't find a solution.

Assume the following code:

```
import numpy as np
A,_,_ = np.meshgrid(np.arange(5),np.arange(7),np.arange(10))
B = (rand(7,10)*5).astype(int)
```

How can I slice `A` using `B` so that `B` represent the indexes in the first and last dimensions of `A` (I.e `A[magic] = B`)?

I have tried

- `A[:,B,:]` which doesn't work due to peculiarities of advanced indexing.
- `A[:,B,np.arange(10)]` generates 7 copies of the matrix I'm after
- `A[np.arange(7),B,np.arange(10)]` gives the error:

> `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this alternative error message helps you: `IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,) (7,10) (10,)` for the ValueError you see. It is the right idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These both work:

```py
A[0, B, 0]
A[B, B, B]
```

Really, only the `B` in axis `1` matters, the others can be any range that will broadcast to `B.shape` and are limited by `A.shape[0]` (for axis `1`) and `A.shape[2]` (for axis `2`), for a ridiculous example:

```py
A[range(7) + range(3), B, range(9,-1, -1)]
```

But you don't want to use `:` because then you'll get, as you said, `7` or `10` (or both!) "copies" of the array you want.

```py
A, _, _ = np.meshgrid(np.arange(5),np.arange(7),np.arange(10))
B = (rand(7,10)*A.shape[1]).astype(int)

np.allclose(B, A[0, B, 0])
#True
np.allclose(B, A[B, B, B])
#True
np.allclose(B, A[range(7) + range(3), B, range(9,-1, -1)])
#True
```